# Jest/Angular: `Unexpected token 'export'` when running tests

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I have this error when running jest tests in my angular10 project:

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I tried various online guides, and this in my jest config:

```
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@citi-icg-172888/ng-mito)/"
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
```

(tried both of these props standalone and together)

I know this is due to specific dependency, it happens in every component importing it.
this is the code causing the error:

```
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './accordion';
```

The dependency works fine and compiles as part of project, the issue only arises in Jest tests

Comment: Do you have a working example?

Comment: @tmhao2005 i dont understand the question?

Comment: I meant a reproducible repo to contain the error?